# How to replace element with random elements?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I want to achieve that every element in the maze is randomly chosen, but in my code, it is always either just A, B or C. What did I do wrong?

```
import random
new_entry = random.choice(['A ', 'B', 'C'])

def generate(size):
  y =[' '] * size
  #print(y)
  list=[' '] * size
  for i, n in enumerate(list):
    maze[i]= y
  for i in range(len(list)):
    for j in range(len(list)):
      list[i][j]= new_entry
  print(list)
```

so for example I wish to get a list like this, if size=2:
list= [[A,B],[C,A]]

Comment: `new_entry` is a variable, and you only assign to it once at the top of your program. After that, you just reuse the value. To make it give a different value every time, turn it into a function (`def new_entry`) and call it `new_entry()`

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

The problem is the way maze is created, please view the following code -

```
import random


def generate(size):
  maze= []
  for i in range(size):
    maze.append([])
    for j in range(size):
      maze[i].append(random.choice(['A ', 'B', 'C']))
  print(maze)
```

You should choose the random value on each iteraion -

```
def generate(size):
  y =[' '] * size
  #print(y)
  list=[' '] * size
  for i, n in enumerate(list):
    maze[i]= y
  for i in range(len(list)):
    for j in range(len(list)):
      list[i][j]= random.choice(['A ', 'B', 'C'])
  print(list)
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked, but all the inner list are the same in the List, can I somehow avoid this? (like list=[[A,B],[A,B]], but I wish to get list=[[A,C],[B,A]] or something like that. I tried to delete the for j part, but then my list stopped being a 2D list.

Comment: @Anonym please see my update

Comment: Suggest to add not to use the keyword `list`

Comment: I agree, anyhow it is not used in the modified solution

Answer (score 1):

You chose the value of new_entry at the start and it should change every time you use it in a for cycle. This code just adds the same value you defined outside your function.